# Prove that $\Delta = {\{(x,x);x}$ in ${X\}}$ in $X\times X$ can be written as an intersection of open sets iff X is $T_1$.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $\Delta = {\{(x,x);x}$ in ${X\}}$ in $X\times X$ can be written as an intersection of open sets **iff** X is $T_1$.

The topology in $X\times X$ is the product topology. $T_1$ is the first separation axiom.

Edit: Sorry for the lack of information, I had no clue of how to prove it.

Here's what i thought about: The $\Leftarrow$ direction was already answered below. Regarding the $\Rightarrow$ direction: Let $\Delta$ $=\bigcap V_\alpha$, $V_\alpha$ open sets. Then, given $(x,x)$ $\in$ $X\times X$, and $(x,y)$ $\in$ $X\times X$, such that $x\neq y $, there is an open set $V_{\alpha_0}$ which contains $(x,x)$, and does not contain $(x,y)$. But we know there is $(x,x)$ $\in$ $W=A\times B$ $\subset V_{\alpha_0}$ where $A$ and $B$ are open. Therefore, we have found an open set $B$ for which $x \in B$ and $y$ is not in $B$. We conclude that $X$ is $T_1$.

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! As Sahiba has pointed out, your question currently lacks important details such as what you've tried so far, what you think could work, etc. Your question, as it stands, is unlikely to be well received.

Comment: A complete proof of the harder direction is in my post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2306879/4280

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing that a topological space is ${\rm T}_1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306420/showing-that-a-topological-space-is-rm-t-1)

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is $T_1$, then so is $X \times X$.  If $x \neq y$, then $X \times X - \{(x,y)\}$ is open.
Use those sets to find the required collection of open sets.

Conversely, if X not T1, then some distinct x,y
with for all open U nhood x, y in U.

If Delta subset open O, then since (x,x) in O,
there's some open UxV with (x,x) in UxV subset O.
Whence x in V, y in V and (x,y) in O.

As x /= y, any intersection of open sets that
contains Delta will have an off diagonal element.

Comment: and the other direction?

Answer (score 0):

HINT. If $x,y,z$ belong to $X$ with $y\ne x\ne z$ let $A_y$ and $A_z$ be open in $X$ with $x\in A_y$ and $x\in A_z$ and  $y\not \in A_y$ and $z\not \in A_z.$  Then $A_y\times A_z$ is open in $X\times X.$ Consider $\cap \{A_y\times A_z: y\ne x\ne z\}$.

The $T_1$ property for any space $S$ is equivalent to the property that $\{p\}$ is the intersection of all of the neighborhoods of $p,$ for each $p\in S.$ More general than your Q: The product of any collection of $T_n$ spaces is a $T_n$ space for $n\leq 3\frac {1}{2}. $

Comment: In the first part are you proving the diagonal is the intersection of open sets?  How is the second part a generalization of  the problem?  It wasn not about showing the product of two T1 spaces is T1.

Comment: It suffices that $X^2$ is $T_1$. In a $T_1$ space $S$ any $T\subset S$ is the intersection of a family of open sets because $T=\cap \{S$ \ $\{p\}: p\in S$ \ $T\}.$

Comment: Sure, but that's only one direction of the problem.